# Referencing problem

Tags: bibtex

I am using IEEE template and having a problem that the last BibTex Reference is shifted

Can any one suspect the problem

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{literatur}
    @ELECTRONIC{7,
  title = {{Simulation of Urban MObility (Sumo)}},
  url = {http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Main_Page},
  owner = {},
  timestamp = {2015.06.15}
}

@ELECTRONIC{8,
  title = {{Microsoft Excel}},
  url = {https://products.office.com},
  owner = {},
  timestamp = {2015.06.15}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid  that the problem might be the picture on the left as it is taking more than its margin then it is causing that shift but not sure.

Comment: Does the formatting problem go away if you omit the picture on the left?

Comment: it changed but not went away became more to left

Comment: It appears that the formatting issue cannot be understood, let alone fixed, without you providing the code in the form of a compilable example (i.e., something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that reproduces the issue.